# Stream writes only 512 bytes to a file on FTP server using C#

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to copy a file from my local computer to an FTP server using C#. 
When I use the code below, the file is fully copied to the FTP server but **the original lines are cut into pieces of only 512 bytes long while they should be 1152,1126 or 1024 bytes long. ** The example file I used has now 16 lines instead of 7.

```
    public void uploadLOTFILE(string username, string password)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.mine/mypathandfilename");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        System.IO.Stream rs = request.GetRequestStream();

        var lines = File.ReadLines(@"myLocalFile.txt");
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);                
            Console.WriteLine("buffer.length:" + buffer.Length.ToString());
            rs.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        }
        rs.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
      }
```

Output from the Console.writeline for an example file:

> buffer.length:1152
>
> buffer.length:1126
>
> buffer.length:1152
>
> buffer.length:1152
>
> buffer.length:1152
>
> buffer.length:1152
>
> buffer.length:1024

I've also used the exact copy from msdn  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx) but this had the same result.

**Edit:**
Also tried the following code:
            string filePath = @"myFilePath";
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp");

```
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
                requestStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

It gives the same result. The file is fully copied but every 512 bytes a newline is added.

With FileZilla I can do a correct FTP transfer of the same type of files.

Comment: *"the file is fully copied to the FTP server but the lines are only 512 bytes long"* - That does not make sense. So is the file fully copied or not?

Comment: How do you check that the lines are only 512 lines long?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you upload the file by lines?

Comment: Do you get correct result, when you upload the file using a regular FTP client?

Comment: You realise you're converting from UTF8 to ASCII, right? Also, is "myLocalFile.txt" definitely encoded as UTF8? It's not, say, UTF16? Or ANSI?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : The lines from the original file are split into multiple lines in the new file. (original file has 7 lines, file on FTP server has 16 lines of max 512 bytes long). I'm copying line by line because I hoped this would fix the issue of the limited bytes on each line. I've also tried to do a "full copy at once" like in the msdn link but without succes.

Comment: @MatthewWatson : the file is ANSI. I changed the Encoding.ASCII to Encoding.Default but also without any success.

Comment: Again: 1) How do you check that the lines are only 512 lines long?  2) Do you get correct result, when you upload the file using a regular FTP client?

Comment: 1) I can open the files directly on the client in a text editor and see it. 2) Yes, this is how it goes now, a person manually uploads the file to the server, but now I want the program to do it.

Comment: Using the new code: When you upload the file, does it have a different size (in FTP client file panel) after an upload (comparing to the original local file)?

Comment: I tested it and here under you can find the result. Seems like all the data is copied the way FileZilla does it. 
After C# FTP upload: 8.192 bytes - 
Original file local copy: 7.922 bytes - 
Copied using FileZilla: 8.192 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the build-in windows FTP that is accessible using the cmd.

```
            string[] lines = { username, password, "remote directory", "put " + "\"" + filePath + "\"" , "bye"};
        // WriteAllLines creates a file, writes a collection of strings to the file,
        // and then closes the file.  You do NOT need to call Flush() or Close().
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("full file path of your script", lines);
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"ftp -s:" + "\"" + "full file path of your script" + "\"" + " remote device");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
```